# How do I get a list of the top performing funds between two given dates?

Tags: mutual-funds, etf, index-fund, yahoo-finance, historical-analysis

Between dates X and Y return a list of the top performing funds, indexes, ETFs, etc for that date range. 
i.e. if a lump sum had been invested at date X, a list of which funds had the top performance by date Y. Is there any way to do this?

Does Google or Yahoo finance or Morningstar allow this and I'm just missing how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of from the back of my head is http://finviz.com/map.ashx, which display a nice map and allows for different intervals. It has different scopes (S&P500, ETFs, World), but does not allow for specific date ranges, though.

Answer (score 1):

I found one such tool here: [Point-to-Point Returns tool](http://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/h2_point2point.asp?start_date=07-Dec-2011&end_date=06-Dec-2012&acode=&ocode=&type=&Vriskrating=&nasset=&investment=&pbut=Get%20Data)